# CUDA returned error code 77 after launching

Tags: cuda

I have the next struct:

```
typedef struct
{
    float* coordinates;
} Point;
```

And the next function in CUDA:

```
cudaError_t calculateCenterUsingCuda(Point* point, const int NUM_OF_DIMENSIONS, const int NUM_OF_POINTS)
{
    Point* point_dev;

    cudaError_t cudaStatus;

    cudaStatus = cudaSetDevice(0);
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cudaSetDevice failed!  Do you have a CUDA-capable GPU installed?");
    }

    cudaStatus = cudaMalloc((void**)&point_dev, 1 * sizeof(Point));
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cudaMalloc failed!");
    }

    cudaStatus = cudaMalloc((void**)&point_dev->coordinates, NUM_OF_DIMENSIONS * sizeof(float));
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cudaMalloc failed!");
    }

    cudaStatus = cudaMemcpy(point_dev, point, 1 * sizeof(Point), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cudaMemcpy failed!");
    }

    cudaStatus = cudaMemcpy(point_dev->coordinates, point->coordinates, NUM_OF_DIMENSIONS * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cudaMemcpy failed!");
    }

    calculateCenter<<<1, 52>>>(point_dev, NUM_OF_POINTS);

    cudaStatus = cudaGetLastError();
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "calculateCenterlaunch failed: %s\n", cudaGetErrorString(cudaStatus));
    }

    cudaStatus = cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cudaDeviceSynchronize returned error code %d after launching calculateCenter!\n", cudaStatus);
    }

    // Copy output vector from GPU buffer to host memory.
    cudaStatus = cudaMemcpy(point, point_dev, 1 * sizeof(Point), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cudaMemcpy failed!");
    }

    cudaStatus = cudaMemcpy(point->coordinates, point_dev->coordinates, NUM_OF_DIMENSIONS * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cudaMemcpy failed!");
    }

    cudaStatus = cudaDeviceReset();
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cudaDeviceReset failed!");
    }

    return cudaStatus;
}
```

And the `calculateCenter` is:

```
__global__ void calculateCenter(Point* point, const int NUM_OF_POINTS)
{
    int i = threadIdx.x;
    point->coordinates[i] = point->coordinates[i] / NUM_OF_POINTS;
    printf("%d\n", i);
}
```

Basically I using the CUDA I create an average points that divide each coordinate in the point to the number of points (default is 4)
The default number of dimensions is 52.

But when I run this code there is an error:

```
cudaDeviceSynchronize returned error code 77 after launching calculateCenter!
```

Any help why this is happened?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your code has some issue in the way pointers are managed. The line

```
cudaStatus = cudaMalloc((void**)&point_dev->coordinates, NUM_OF_DIMENSIONS * sizeof(float));
```

is wrong. At this stage, `point_dev` is a pointer to device memory, and the host API function call `cudaMalloc` is expecting a target address in the host memory space. The storage location of the device pointer is a device pointer in your case, which is wrong.

You can fix that by using an intermediate `Point` data structure and store device pointers in in then copy to the device:

```
cudaError_t calculateCenterUsingCuda(Point* point, const int NUM_OF_DIMENSIONS, const int NUM_OF_POINTS)
{
    Point* point_dev;

    Point point_for_dev;

    cudaError_t cudaStatus;

    cudaStatus = cudaSetDevice(0);
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cudaSetDevice failed!  Do you have a CUDA-capable GPU installed?");
    }

    cudaStatus = cudaMalloc((void**)&point_dev, 1 * sizeof(Point));
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cudaMalloc failed!");
    }

    cudaStatus = cudaMalloc((void**)&(point_for_dev.coordinates), NUM_OF_DIMENSIONS * sizeof(float));
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cudaMalloc failed!");
    }

    cudaStatus = cudaMemcpy(point_dev, &point_for_dev, 1 * sizeof(Point), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cudaMemcpy failed!");
    }

    cudaStatus = cudaMemcpy(point_for_dev.coordinates, point->coordinates, NUM_OF_DIMENSIONS * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cudaMemcpy failed!");
    }

    calculateCenter <<< 1, NUM_OF_DIMENSIONS >>>(point_dev, NUM_OF_POINTS);

    cudaStatus = cudaGetLastError();
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "calculateCenterlaunch failed: %s\n", cudaGetErrorString(cudaStatus));
    }

    cudaStatus = cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cudaDeviceSynchronize returned error code %d after launching calculateCenter!\n", cudaStatus);
    }

    // Copy output vector from GPU buffer to host memory.
    cudaStatus = cudaMemcpy(point->coordinates, point_for_dev.coordinates, NUM_OF_DIMENSIONS * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cudaMemcpy failed!");
    }

    cudaStatus = cudaDeviceReset();
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cudaDeviceReset failed!");
    }

    return cudaStatus;
}
```

This way, the host API methods are using host pointers all along.

Deep copy of pointer-based structures need specific treatment.

Comment: Thanks but are you sure with : `cudaStatus = cudaMemcpy(point, point_dev, 1 * sizeof(Point), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);`? the point_for_dev coords sims to be zero after the kernel wotk

Comment: @ShayZambrovski, well spotted, the fix of your code was incomplete. The copy back of pointer values is pointless, the only relevant part is the contents of the coordinate array. Though supporting more than one point will require more coding work.

Comment: Thanks, but still, after the  `cudaStatus = cudaMemcpy(point->coordinates, point_for_dev.coordinates, NUM_OF_DIMENSIONS * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);` The array is all 0, could you know why?

Comment: @ShayZambrovski, you did not provide any code around the kernel call. Results depend on your initialization. There is only that much I can do with the information you provided. Finally, SO is not a debugging service. If you have subsequent issues on the output values, please consider debugging your code with NSIGHT or cuda-gdb.